# how to render json data into an unordered list with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, list

I am trying to create an inventory section that reads from a json file on the server. I've seen how to do this in a table but haven't had much luck with making a an unordered list. This site is currently using angular 1.6.1

Sample data and html:

```js
angular.module('App', [])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.data = [
        {"id":  0,
      "vinNum": "blank-vin-num",
      "manufacturer": "200",
      "model": "BIKE",
      "bodyType": "Cycle",
      "yearOfVehicle": "2006",
      "stockNum": "11101",
      "colorExt": "GREEN",
      "mileage": "1",
      "dateEntered": "08/08/2007"},

    ];
});



<div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      <h1>Inventory</h1>

      <ul> 
        <li ng-repeat="stuff in data">{{stuff.model}}</li>
        <li ng-repeat="stuff in data">{{stuff.manufacturer}}</li>
        <li ng-repeat="stuff in data">{{stuff.vinNum}}</li>
        <li ng-repeat="stuff in data">{{stuff.bodyType}}</li>
        <li ng-repeat="stuff in data">{{stuff.colorExt}}</li>
        <li ng-repeat="stuff in data">{{stuff.yearOfVehicle}}</li>
        <li ng-repeat="stuff in data">{{stuff.stockNum}}</li>
        <li ng-repeat="stuff in data"> {{stuff.mileage}}</li>
        <li ng-repeat="stuff in data"> {{stuff.dateEntered}}</li>
    </ul>
```

Now this works there is no other vehicle, but once you add another vehicle there will be two vinNums(same thing for every line) together instead of being separate. I am new to using Angular to make a list like this so if someone could help guide me that would be awesome.

Comment: you want to make a table ?

Comment: I'd Like to make it an li if I could if not than table will do. But I am up for suggestions if you have a reliable way to make a table. It is basically an inventory page that will display details about the vehicle in the json file.

Comment: you should make it a table, nor readable and sortable, well aligned

Comment: @AlainIb do you have a link or example I could look at and see how it looks?

Comment: i update my answer

Answer (score 2):

Problem area is usage of `ng-repeat` with `li` element to read the object property.

You can remove `ng-repeat` from `li`, and wrap it in a *div*  like

```
<div ng-repeat="stuff in data">
    <ul> 
        <li>{{stuff.model}}</li>
        <li>{{stuff.manufacturer}}</li>
        <li>{{stuff.vinNum}}</li>
        <li>{{stuff.bodyType}}</li>
        <li>{{stuff.colorExt}}</li>
        <li>{{stuff.yearOfVehicle}}</li>
        <li>{{stuff.stockNum}}</li>
        <li>{{stuff.mileage}}</li>
        <li>{{stuff.dateEntered}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

OR,

You can use nested `ngRepeat`, As `$scope.data` is an array, it can be iterated using `ng-repeat="stuff in data"` then in the second iteration you can iterate properties.

```
<div ng-repeat="stuff in data">
    <ul> 
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in stuff">{{key}}:{{value}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('docsIsolateScopeDirective', [])
    .controller('Controller', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.data = [{
          "id": 0,
          "vinNum": "blank-vin-num"
        }, {
          "id": 1,
          "vinNum": "vinNum2"
        }];
      }
    ]);

})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="docsIsolateScopeDirective">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <div ng-repeat="stuff in data">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in stuff">{{key}}:{{value}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. After I removed my controller, moved my app name around, and added my json data in over your sample data pops up the in the list

Comment: Curious am I able to use this to populate an image link? If the image is uploaded to a offsite server using the url. I used the first solution you gave me btw

Comment: @Ant, I have update answer, And yes you can populate link. I would suggest you to create a function and return the URL based of _id_ or something other property

Answer (score 1):

You better group the item data inside only one "li" element at a time, let's say that every "li" should be every element in the list, not every property of the element.

Try something like this:

```
angular.module('App', [])
```

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

```
$scope.data = [
    {"id":  0,
  "vinNum": "blank-vin-num",
  "manufacturer": "200",
  "model": "BIKE",
  "bodyType": "Cycle",
  "yearOfVehicle": "2006",
  "stockNum": "11101",
  "colorExt": "GREEN",
  "mileage": "1",
  "dateEntered": "08/08/2007"},

];
 });



  <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <h1>Inventory</h1>

        <ul> 
    <li ng-repeat="stuff in data">
            <div>{{stuff.model}}</div>
            <div>{{stuff.manufacturer}}
            <div>{{stuff.vinNum}}</div>
            <div>{{stuff.bodyType}}</div>
            <div>{{stuff.colorExt}}</div>
            <div>{{stuff.yearOfVehicle}}</div>
            <div>{{stuff.stockNum}}</div>
            <div>{{stuff.mileage}}</div>
            <div>{{stuff.dateEntered}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a table to display it well formated with search and order

ngTable is nice for that : http://ng-table.com/#/

working example :
https://plnkr.co/edit/JNKBydXCLtxuvQykirUL?p=preview

1 HTML :

```
 <!-- load script and css for ngtable -->
<link rel="stylesheet"; href="https://unpkg.com/ng-table@2.0.2/bundles/ng-table.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ng-table@2.0.2/bundles/ng-table.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
        <td data-title="'id'" filter="{id: 'text'}" filter-data="id" sortable="'id'">{{ row.id }}</td>
          <td data-title="'manufacturer'" filter="{manufacturer: 'text'}" sortable="'manufacturer'">{{ row.manufacturer }}</td>
          <td data-title="'model'" filter="{model: 'text'}" sortable="'model'">{{ row.model }}</td>
          <td data-title="'yearOfVehicle'" filter="{yearOfVehicle: 'text'}" sortable="'yearOfVehicle'">{{ row.yearOfVehicle }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

2 JAVASCRIPT

```
// inject ngtable dependency : ngTable && NgTableParams
 var app = angular.module('App', ['ngTable'])
      .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $filter, $q, NgTableParams) {
        var  data = [{"id":0,"vinNum":"blank-vin-num","manufacturer":"200","model":"BIKE","bodyType":"Cycle","yearOfVehicle":"2006","stockNum":"11101","colorExt":"GREEN","mileage":"1","dateEntered":"08/08/2007"},{"id":1,"vinNum":"blank-vin-num 1","manufacturer":"300","model":"BIKE 1","bodyType":"Cycle 1","yearOfVehicle":"2007","stockNum":"11101","colorExt":"GREEN","mileage":"1","dateEntered":"08/08/2007"},{"id":2,"vinNum":"blank-vin-num 2","manufacturer":"400","model":"BIKE 2","bodyType":"Cycle 2","yearOfVehicle":"2008","stockNum":"11101","colorExt":"GREEN","mileage":"1","dateEntered":"08/08/2007"},{"id":3,"vinNum":"blank-vin-num 3","manufacturer":"500","model":"BIKE 3","bodyType":"Cycle 3","yearOfVehicle":"2009","stockNum":"11101","colorExt":"GREEN","mileage":"1","dateEntered":"08/08/2007"                    } ];
        $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({page: 1, count: 10}, {data: data});

      })
```